# Java Spring Boot local scope variable make it shared

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Sprint Boot and creating microservices. I have a scenario where an object will be created and it will be used by other methods of the same class and methods of other classes. But scope will be only when this method gets called.

```
Class SharedObject {
  private String name;
  //getters setters
}

 @Service 
 Class FirstServiceImpl {

  @Autowired
  SecondServiceImpl second;

  public void process() {
     SharedObject obj = new SharedObject();
     //...
     process2(obj);
  }

  private void process2(SharedObject obj) {
    //...
    second.process(obj);
  }
  
}

 @Service 
 Class SecondServiceImpl {
  public void process(SharedObject obj) {
       //...
   }
 }
```

Here SharedObject needs to be created in process method of FirstServiceImpl class and that needs to be accessed in rest of the places. But next call of process method of FirstServiceImpl class, it should create a new object.

Considering this, I can pass to all the methods it requires. But is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: so what is your question or may be what do you think is not OK with your current approach?

Comment: Can I know the reason why are you creating object [SharedObject] inside process() method? SharedObject  needs some inputs that are present inside process() method?

Comment: Every time when process() method is called, a new instance of shared object needs to be created and this instance needs to be passed to all the methods down the line, as it will be used in its corresponding method. Here I need to keep passing it as an argument to all the methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ThreadLocal (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) for this use case. But use it with care, it can easily cause memory leaks if not done properly.

There are some interesting articles to read on ThreadLocal.

https://dzone.com/articles/an-alternative-approach-to-threadlocal-using-sprin-1   - ***Better implementation of ThreadLocal***

https://plumbr.io/blog/locked-threads/how-to-shoot-yourself-in-foot-with-threadlocals

]https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/01/threadlocal-memory-leak-in-java-web.html#axzz7iil9FiAC